# Wordpress website hacked, how to refind the origin to secure it?

Tags: security, wordpress

My wordpress website was hacked several days ago. I can't succeed to find the origin of the vulnerability (a plugin, or wordpress-self)... If it can help you, I have a strange files called onlyindex.zip and smtphec.php on the root dir of my FTP server.

[If it can Help you, here some files that have nothing to do upon the www directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IptMx.png)

I looked the logs but it is impossible there is more than 50000 requests a day

Comment: This does not belong here. **Maybe** it belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com - but even then, its not that appropriate and you have not provided sufficient information. If you can establish the hack has not spread outside web user and virtualhost, deleting the site, installing from a backup and securing is not the worst solution.

Comment: You may be able to find the trigger/narrow down how the hack occurred by looking at logs around 05/17/20  13:15:51 - as that is likely roughly when the attack occurred. If you can find an element of the attack in your log, you may be able to get further info on how it unfolded and how bad. it is by grepping your logs based on IP address.  Similarly, searching the filesystem for files with timestamps around that time may give you some hints.

Comment: Also check your ftp server logs in case the site was compromised via ftp.